# Finding the normal equation

Tags: calculus, least-squares

After my semester at Umich my mathematics professor issued me an abundance of problems to keep my head in the game during the summer. One of the questions which threw me off was finding the normal equations that minimize the approximation error. I must admit he never taught normal equations before or least squares for that matter. I get the basic understanding of least squares and normal equations. My issue is the theoretical aspect of applying the formula to variables instead of numbers. Can someone explain to me in layman's term, how do i solve:
the normal equations for $$g^* = \left[g_1^*,g_2^*\right]$$
that minimize the approximation error in the least square sense

$$g^* = \arg\max_g \left(\sum_{n=0}^N [f_n -F(x_n,g)]^2\right)$$
in the case of:

$$F(x,g) = g_1 e^{g_2x} $$

Comment: I was trying to improve the readability, but hmmm... what  is $e$?

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect format but e is suppose to be is a variable.

Comment: I added an image for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested to find $g_1$ and $g_2$ that maximizes

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \left[f_n-F(x_n,g)\right]^2=\sum_{n=0}^N \left[f_n-g_1\exp(g_2x_n)\right]^2.$$

To do so, I would take partial differentiation wrt $g_1$ and partial differentiation wrt $g_2$ and equate them to zero.

I obtain:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \left[f_n-g_1\exp(g_2x_n)\right] \exp(g_2x_n)=0$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \left[f_n-g_1\exp(g_2x_n)\right]g_1x_n \exp(g_2x_n)=0$$

In particular, from the first eqution, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^N f_n \exp(g_2x_n)=\sum_{n=0}^Ng_1\exp(2g_2x_n)$$

and $$g_1=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^N f_n \exp(g_2x_n)}{\sum_{n=0}^N\exp(2g_2x_n)}.$$

Similarly, assumingly that $g_1 \neq 0$, from the second equation, we have

$$g_1=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^N f_nx_n \exp(g_2x_n)}{\sum_{n=0}^Nx_n\exp(2g_2x_n)}.$$

Comment: Okay two questions, what is wrt? And I am a little confused. That equation doesn't look linear. Without having an values to plug in and relying straight on variables, it tends to get me a bit confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain to me what you did. Is the second answer the answer to the solution or the first? I'm sorry for the amateur questions, i never really had a course in least squares.

Comment: wrt means "with respect to". they are indeed nonlinear. We are suppose to find $g_1$ and $g_2$ that satisfies the equations. To obtain the first equation, I I treat $g_2$ as a constant while I differentiate the objective function with respect to $g_1$ and equate it to zero. I do the opposite thing for the second equation.

Comment: $x_n$ and $f_n$ are given to you, we just have to solve for $g_1$ and $g_2$ perhaps numerically.

Comment: I guess since the question didn't give any numerical inputs then the answer above should suffice.

Comment: Can you simplify how you got g1? By doing so i could understand how to go about doing g2.

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: OH my, I am super confused now, with respect to g1.

Comment: Thank you for your patience by the way.

Comment: Perhaps solve it numerically?

Comment: Not really, but like the individual steps you took to get the answer.

Comment: Ok, to see how to differentiate with respect to $g_1$  Try differentiating term like $(5-3g_1)^2$ using chain rule. can u get $2(5-3g_1)(-3)$? In our question $5$ is like the $f$ term, $3$ is like the $\exp(g_2x_n)$ term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40250/discussion-between-micheal-c-and-siongthyegoh).